# Display today’s date and the name of the month, in lower case, for the month 4 month’s hence (ie today’s date + 4 months)

Tags: sql, string, oracle, datetime

Hey guys how would this be written? I don't know how to write it to where it shows the months being added in lower case.

I know how to show the current month in lower case but not the future date.

This is what I have done so far.

```
SELECT  current_date, to_char (current_date, lower ('month')), add_months (current_date, 4)
```

from dual

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT sysdate, 
    to_char (sysdate, 'month'), 
    to_char(add_months(sysdate, 4), 'month') 
from dual
```

Oracle's `to_char()` follows the case given in format specifier. So specifier `'month'` gives you the full name of month in all lower case, while `'Month'`, for example, would give the first letter of month in capital.

Note that the result of `to_char(... 'month')` is right-padded with space characters. If you want to avoid that, use `'fmmonth'` instead.

Comment: after you add_months to the date, you get the "month" from the date field , SELECT  sysdate, to_char (sysdate, lower ('month')) , to_char(add_months(sysdate, 4), 'month') , to_char(add_months(sysdate, 4), 'Month')  from dual